# Error: Cannot convert the value of '{!pitem.Stock}' to the expected type

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
    <apex:page controller="StoreFrontController" tabStyle="Product__c" >
<apex:form> 
    <apex:pageBlock title="Our Products">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!products}" var="pitem">
                <apex:column headerValue="Product">
                <apex:outputText value="{!pitem.Name}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Condition">
                <apex:outputText value="{!pitem.condition}"/>
                </apex:column>
               <apex:column headerValue="Price">
                <apex:outputText value="{0,number,currency}" style="text-align: right;">
                <apex:param value="{!pitem.Price}"/>
                </apex:outputText>
                   </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Stock">
                <apex:outputText value="{!pitem.stock}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Qty to Buy">
                <apex:inputText value="{!pitem.quantity}" rendered="{! pitem.Stock}"/>
                <apex:outputText value="Out of Stock" rendered="{! NOT(pitem.Stock)}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:commandButton title="Add to Cart" value="{!addToCart}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Cart Contents" id="shopping_cart">
        <apex:outputText value="{!cartContents}" escape="false" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This column will be a form field for entering a quantity to buy, or an out-of-stock notice, based on the value of the
productDisplay.Stock() method for each product.

Comment: Sohail -- you need to post more details (normally I applaud reducing the problem to its essence) -- 1) pItem is some iterator over a list - post the list variable please;  2) the getter for stock must be inside of some class - please post as well

Comment: I have updated my question by the name of this Question in the form of new question: Error: Read only property 'StoreFrontController.productDisplay.quantity'